# How to run multiple js file using node js command line?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I want to start 4 script using node js.

```
myapp
  -script1.js
  -script2.js
  -script3.js
  -app.js
  -package.json
  ....
  ....
```

I tried running it using below

```
node script1.js && node script2.js && node script3.js && node app.js

node script1.js & node script2.js & node script3.js & node app.js
```

But its not starting all script it only start `script1.js`.

How to do it ?

Comment: are you exiting script1.js with non zero exit code ?

Comment: No actually my script files are services listening to specific code

Comment: single ampersand is used for running scripts in background

Comment: It's difficult to answer without seeing the actual script. If all of them are independent scripts then please use the command I have mentioned in the answer below

Comment: simply use `&` instead of `&&` as explained here :https://itnext.io/4-solutions-to-run-multiple-node-js-or-npm-commands-simultaneously-9edaa6215a93
worked for me on mac (node 14.7)

Answer (score 5):

```
$ node script-1.js  && node script-2.js && node script-3.js && node app.js
I am script-1
I am script-2
I am script-3
I am app.js
```

It is working.

Maybe your **script1.js** is blocking those other scripts that are on the queue.

Node runs it in a synchronous way.

If you want to run those scripts in parallel.

You can use npm package called [concurrently](https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently)

**In command line.**

```
$ concurrently "node script-1.js" "node script-2.js" "node script-3.js" "node app.js"
[3] I am app.js
[2] I am script-3
[0] I am script-1
[1] I am script-2
[2] node script-3.js exited with code 0
[3] node app.js exited with code 0
[0] node script-1.js exited with code 0
[1] node script-2.js exited with code 0
Done in 1.07s.
```

Or you can put it on your **package.json scripts**.

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "concurrently \"node script-1.js\" \"node script-2.js\" \"node script-3.js\" \"node app.js\""
}
```

It will run multiple commands concurrently / in asynchronous way.

**Hope it helps. :)**

Answer (score 1):

Try this. it will execute all scripts irrespective of the exit code of the previous script

`node script1.js; node script2.js; node script3.js; node app.js`

Comment: I tried it give Error: Cannot find module 'D:\myapp\script1.js;'

Answer (score 0):

Use the pipe operator (windows). node service1.js | node service2.js

Answer (score 0):

### you can use npm concurrently.

```
first install npm install -g concurrently
```

### Then:

```
Run npm init to the parent directory of both of the projects.
the parent directory's package.json file will look like this.

{
  "name": "project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "concurrently \"npm run develop --prefix project1\" \"npm run develop --prefix project2\""
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

### Then:

```
 write inside the "start" like above . just change the folder name of project1 and project2 with your projects name.
```

### Then:

```
npm start
```